# options_from_collection_for_select wont allow selection by variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

The two snippets of code below, the `options_from_collection_for_select` works for setting the `:selected` when i use a set value, but when I use `@posts.user_id` it fails.

Why is this working?

```ruby
select_tag "user-dropdown", options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 'id', 'fname', **11**), :class =>'form-control'
```

But this is not?

```ruby
select_tag "user-dropdown", options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 'id', 'fname', **@posts.user_id**), :class =>'form-control'
```

Comment: are you trying to implement inside a form ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select_tag "user-dropdown", options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 'id', 'fname', **@posts.user_id**), :class =>'form-control'
```

What is this **@posts.user_id** you are trying to display in your options ?

**select_tag with options_for_select example**

An example of using options_for_select with select_tag

```
select_tag 'user_id', options_for_select(@users.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] })
```

**This would generate something like:**

```
<select id="user_id" name="user_id">
  <option value="1">Brad</option>
  <option value="2">Angie</option>
  <option value="3">Jenny</option>
</select>
```